# How to fix string size selection error in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

val textoData = itemView.findViewById(R.id.texto_data_abastecimento)
textoData.text = abastecimento.datam.toString().subSequence(0..10)

```
        val textoHora = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.texto_hora_abastecimento)
        textoHora.text = abastecimento.hodomDm.toString().subSequence(0..5)
```

I'm trying to use only the first 5 characters for display on the adapter and I end up getting the following error:

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=6

Comment: This question needs a lots of formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use the `substring(0,5)` extension function of Kotlin standard library.

```
    textoHora.text = abastecimento.hodomDm.toString().substring(0,5)
```